# Can't switch to edit mode for some objects, but can for others

Tags: edit-mode

(like others asking similarly to myself) I'm just getting started with Blender.

I'm following [a tutorial series on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyJWoyVx_XI&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U) and thought to give myself something more interesting than creating a single donut, why not three donuts?

I'm trying to switch to edit mode for my frosting on my donuts to pull down and create the drizzle, but I can only go into edit mode for a single frosting object.

Frosting.002 (selected in the scene collection) is allowing me to enter edit mode:
[image: Frosting.002 selected]

But I cannot enter edit mode for the other two, even though I have them selected in the scene collection (as pictured below)
[image: Frosting.000 selected]
[image: Frosting.001 selected]

I'm not sure what I'm not doing correctly, as it seems this is usually remedied by selecting the appropriate object first (which I thought I did) or restarting Blender. Neither have worked for me, unfortunately. This leads me to believe I've set my objects into a state that needs to be un-done, but I'm not sure what that would be or how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer ?

Comment: @Aster17 Just gave it a try. Unfortunately no dice. I can jump to edit mode for literally anything else but the two frosting objects listed above.

Comment: try deleting those 2 frostings and and create them again

Comment: You may have selected multiple objects for editing and then deselected some of those objects in that mode. Does this vid help? https://youtu.be/UX8s2TY14yg?t=74